# Scroll on inner div?

Tags: css, html

I wish to have my 'browse' section scroll.

```
 <section id="browse">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a4H6K/

At the minute nothing is happening. I hide the overflow on the body and set scroll auto on the browse section. The browse section also has a height set at 100%.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For setting height in `%`, the parent element should have a height set explicitly.

In your case, `<main>` does not have a height set.

You've to set a height for all the parents as follows:

```
html, main {
 height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4H6K/1/)

**Update**

*As per comments,* for seeing the full scroll bar, we need to take the height of `<nav>` into account, hence the `section#browse` can't have `100%` width.

for eg,

```
nav{
 background: red;
 height:20px;
}
#browse{
 height: -webkit-calc(100% - 20px);
 height: -moz-calc(100% - 20px);
 height: -ms-calc(100% - 20px);
 height: calc(100% - 20px);
 overflow: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4H6K/4/)

Comment: May want to state they missed out main as well as saying you need to do all the parents heights. +1 :D

Comment: This does not work. Check your fiddle, the content is not scrolling.

Comment: sorry, it was the OP's fiddle, not the updated one, updated now.. :)

Comment: Thanks but your fiddle still doesnt work properly. The scroll bar is being cut off at the bottom.

Comment: @panthro Because of your top bar. This question was about getting it to scroll.

Comment: @panthro that's because you're not taking the height of `<nav>` into account. you've to reduce the height of section

Comment: So this solution is not complete then is it? I can't see the entire scroll bar.

Comment: @panthro Erm, the solution is complete. You asked how to get the div to scroll. That has been answered.

Comment: Your solution expresses the height of the nav, not really a good idea is it

Comment: @panthro As I said before this has been answered. You should now go look for a solution to fixed the next problem you have. If you really can't find out (there are loads) then make a question.